# Mui Data table header is not sticky after applying CSS on table body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable

I Need to show First column of table is sticky , I am able to do for first column of table body but not for header , when I apply CSS for Table body automatically header sticky is not working.

```
  import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material/styles';
const getMuiTheme = () =>
  createTheme({
    components: {
      MUIDataTableToolbar: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            minHeight: '50px',
            display: 'flex',
          },
          actions: {
            display: 'flex',
            flex: 'inherit',
          },
        },
      },
     
        
     
      MUIDataTableHeadCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            
              '&:first-child': {
                opacity: 1, // Set the opacity value you desire (0.0 to 1.0) for the first column cells
                position: 'sticky',
                left: 0,
                zIndex: 1,
                backgroundColor: 'white', // Set the background color as needed
              },
            // borderBottom: 'none !important',
            borderTop: '1px solid #d9d9d9',
            fontSize: '14px !important',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold !important',
            padding: '10px 16px 10px 16px',
            // borderRight: 'none',
          },
          toolButton: {
            fontSize: '14px !important',
            fontFamily: 'helvetica !important',
            fontWeight: 'bold !important',
          },
        },
      },
     
      MuiTableCell: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: {
            '&:first-child': {
              opacity: 1, // Set the opacity value you desire (0.0 to 1.0) for the first column cells
              position: 'sticky',
              left: 0,
              zIndex: 1,
              backgroundColor: 'white', // Set the background color as needed
            },
            color: "#000000", // This sets the text color for all cells
          },
        },
      },
        
    },
  });

   <TableContainer className={classes.container}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={getMuiTheme()}>
          <MUIDataTable
            // title='Search Results'
            // components={{
            //   TableFooter: CustomFilterList,
            // }}
            data={data}
            columns={headers}
            options={options}
            // components={components}
          />
        </ThemeProvider>
      </TableContainer>
```

I want to see both table header first column and body first column should be sticky , when i scroll left it should be sticky and opacity should apply